# KeyError in project

Tags: python

Doing a project for a class where I have to make a text based game, and I am getting a KeyError upon running my code.

These are the 2 parts of my code where it says the error is stemming from

Line 26

```
def get_item(state):
    return rooms[state]['Item']
```

Line 42

```
item = get_item(state)
```

Here is my full code, I have been looking and just can't seem to find the solution. If anyone can see what I am missing, I would really appreciate it.

```
rooms = {
    'Outside': {'South': 'Main Hall'},
    'Main Hall': {'North': 'Outside', 'East': 'Dining Room', 'West': 'Bedroom', 'South': 'Living Room'},
    'Bedroom': {'West': 'Room with Villain', 'South': 'Bathroom', 'Item': 'Hat'},
    'Dining Room': {'South': 'Kitchen', 'West': 'Main Hall', 'Item': 'Chair leg'},
    'Kitchen': {'West': 'Living Room', 'North': 'Dining Room', 'East': 'Garage', 'Item': 'Snack'},
    'Living Room': {'North': 'Main Hall', 'East': 'Kitchen', 'Item': 'TV Remote'},
    'Garage': {'West': 'Kitchen', 'Item': 'Bike'},
    'Bathroom': {'North': 'Bedroom', 'South': 'Room with Villain', 'Item': 'Toilet paper'},
    'Room with Villain': {'East': 'Bedroom', 'North': 'Room with Villain', 'Item': 'Witch'}

}
state = 'Outside'


def get_new_state(state, direction):
    new_state = state
    for i in rooms:
        if i == state:
            if direction in rooms[i]:
                new_state = rooms[i][direction]
    return new_state


def get_item(state):
    return rooms[state]['Item']


def show_instructions():
    print('Witch Hunt Adventure Game')
    print('Collect the 6 items to win the game, or the Witch will attack you.')
    print('Movement commands: go South, go North, go East, or go West')
    print("To add an item to your inventory: get 'item_name'")


show_instructions()
Inventory = []
items = ['Hat', 'Chair leg', 'Snack', 'Bike', 'Toilet paper', 'TV Remote']
while (1):
    print('You are in ', state)
    print('Inventory:', Inventory)
    item = get_item(state)
    print('You see a ', item)
    print('--------------------')
    if item == 'Witch':
        print('YOU HAVE BEEN CAUGHT! GAME OVER')
        exit(0)
    direction = input('Enter your move: ')
    if direction == 'go East' or direction == 'go West' or direction == 'go North' or direction == 'go South':
        direction = direction[3:]
        new_state = get_new_state(state, direction)
        if new_state == state:
            print('There is a wall there')
        else:
            state = new_state
    elif direction == str('get ' + item):
        if item in Inventory:
            print('Item already taken, go to another room!')
        else:
            Inventory.append(item)
    else:
        print('Invalid input or move or item')
    if len(Inventory) == 6:
        print('Congratulations! After collecting all of those items, you have defeated the witch!')
        exit(0)
```

Comment: when `state` is `"Outside"`, then `rooms[state]` is `{'South': 'Main Hall'}`. The only key here is `"South"`, `"Item"` is not a valid key

Comment: you don't have `'item'` key in `outside' dictionary which is inside `'rooms'` dictionary, hence the KeyError. A KeyError is raised when you pass a key to the dictionary which does not exist in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of your rooms don't have items in them, for example

```
rooms['Outside'] = {'South': 'Main Hall'}
```

so attempting to access `rooms['Outside']['Item']` will fail. You should perhaps use:

```
def get_item(state):
    return rooms[state].get('Item', None)
```

This will return `None` if there are no items in the room. In your main code you can then check for that:

```
    item = get_item(state)
    if item is not None:
        print('You see a ', item)
```